# How to create a Nuget Tools package who installs an executable in a fixed location

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, csproj

I'm developing a Console .Net471 project (csproj) with a CommandLine Tool.

The .csproj has the appropriated lines:

```
<IsTool>true</IsTool>
<PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>
```

The nuget package installs under:

```
<solution>/packages/<idpackage>/tools
```

So, it is not accesible as a command line tool under any solution's project.

I want redirect package output to `%userprofile%/.nuget/tools/` or similar to have a fixed location for my tools.

But I don't find any documentation about installing tools for MSBUILD 15.0+ or about redirecting installation path.

Comment: I believe you cannot install nuget package wherever you want. What would prevent you from installing it under C:\windows directory...

Comment: It's ok... But in this case... what is the reason to have a "istool" or a "PackAsTool" tags? It is not possible to install a tool in a fix place (ej: solution root)?

Comment: .NET Core has the concept of global tools - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools NuGet on its own does not have this concept. PackAsTool is a property used when generating a .NET Core global tool.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use `IsTool` or `PackAsTool` for .NET Framework 4.8 and lower.  Fundamentally, there are three major "worlds" of packaging nuget packages:

1. *.csproj using .NET Core SDK project format (with [NuGet 4.0+ `PackageReference` support instead of `packages.config` and MSBuild 15.1+ first-class support for NuGet `pack` and `restore` as well-known MSBuild targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets)).
2. *.csproj using Legacy .NET Framework SDK project format
3. *.csproj using Legacy .NET Framework ToolsVersion project format

For simple scenarios, `*.csproj using Legacy .NET Framework SDK project format` works.  However, there are many things you cannot do with this combination.  Here is my attempt at breaking it down:

```
|                      |                       | ------------------ Cross-Section of MSBuild Features  ------------------ |
|                      |                       |          |                  |                    |              |        |
| MSBuild Project Type | .NET Runtime          | CLI Tool | PackageReference | FrameworkReference | COMReference | WiX    |
| -------------------- | --------------------- | -------- | ---------------- | ------------------ | ------------ | ------ |
| ToolsVersion         | Legacy .NET Framework | No       | No               | No                 | Yes*         | Yes**  |
| .NET SDK             | Legacy .NET Framework | No       | Yes              | No                 | No***        | No     |
| .NET SDK             | .NET Core             | Yes****  | Yes              | .NET Core 3.0+     | No***        | No     |
```

**1 *** MSBuild lead developer Rainer Sigwald says "`COMReference` is not expected to work" https://github.com/dotnet/installer/issues/1690#issuecomment-485913274
**2 **** WiX requires the old ToolsVersion project references in order to properly build a WiX project for you, by computing all the dependencies it needs to ship.
**3 ***** In particular, you shouldn't expect .NET Core to support COM, because of comments Jan Kotas made referencing the Mono Runtime team's experience with supporting COM.  In particular, Linux does not support Windows Structured Exception Handling, since Linux's base Application Binary Interface is C.  For more, see this example of why it would be unstable for .NET Core to support COM: https://monoinfinito.wordpress.com/series/exception-handling-in-c/ 
**4 ****** .NET Core introduced CLI Tools in [.NET Core 2.1 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools)

This covers a pretty large surface area for packaging applications.  Note that the absence of COM also explains why WiX is pretty much dead technology: WiX is mostly a way to integrate MsiExec into C# projects via a `*.wixproj`, and MsiExec *is* COM under the hood: Every MsiExec package is stored with its metadata in the Windows Registry under the COM-related folders.

#### Now, what's the consequence of this not being possible?

1. You cannot use .NET Core 3.0 tool manifest files to describe such tools.
2. You need to write extra plumbing code on both the "publisher"-side (the Tool) and "consumer"-side (the client using the Tool).

For a real world example of what this looks like, you can check out our project, [`FluentMigrator`](https://github.com/fluentmigrator/fluentmigrator).  Notably, look at `FluentMigrator.Console.csproj` and `FluentMigrator.Console.nuspec`, and then look at how we build our whole solution, and then do a special pack/publish step just for `FluentMigrator.Console.csproj`.  I'm working on an approach to simplify this, but it might be suitable inspiration for you for now.

#### Is there anything else to consider?

Additionally, you might want to look at the open source project, [MSBuild.Sdk.Extras](https://github.com/novotnyllc/MSBuildSdkExtras)

Answer (score 1):

Command line tools shipped as NuGet packages do not need to be installed to a fixed location.

In fact, there is an easy approach, so I use [Obfuscar](https://github.com/obfuscar/obfuscar) as an example.

## Step 1

Prepare a props file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Obfuscar>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\obfuscar.console.exe</Obfuscar>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

## Step 2

Use this props file in your package,

```
    <files>
        <file src="bin\release\obfuscar.console.exe" target="tools" />
        <file src="build\obfuscar.props" target="build" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Now you are done.

All consumers of this NuGet package only need to use `"$(Obfuscar)"` to refer to that console application (no matter the actual physical path).

Comment: Yes, I meant to add this to my answer below (but instead just linked to how `FluentMigrator.Console` is packaged).  What you're doing here is exactly what I do for net461 msbuild assets in my build.targets file.  However, I have an initial step which is to define `<Project InitialTargets="InstallToolsIfNotInstalled">` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-specify-which-target-to-build-first?view=vs-2019

Comment: BTW, @LexLi, please provide feedback on my answer if you can.  It's based on my raw experience working with .NET Core accumulated over the last 4 years.  It's stuff that isn't really documented anywhere - just yeoman knowledge.  Hope you and others find it useful!